# Allow specific user manage & install plugins - WooCommerce/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I try to allow specific user to install and manage plugins. His role is Store Manager (WooCommerce), and this is my functions:

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    
    // Get & Set user ID
    $shopmanager_id = 7;
    $shopmanager = new WP_User( $shopmanager_id );
    
        // Let him manage and install plugins
        $shopmanager->add_cap( 'edit_plugins', true );
        $shopmanager->add_cap( 'install_plugins', true );
    
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

But it's not working. How to achieve that?

Comment: _Not Working_ Not really a very helpful description of an issue

Comment: Just nothing happens. Manager still does not have acces to edit plugins with this code.

Comment: put a `var_dump($shopmanager); die('FUNCTION CALLED');` at the bottom of `add_theme_caps()` and login/logout to see if it dies i.e. if the function is executed at all

Comment: This made page crashed.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I made this in different way. There was some problem with Manager role from WooCommerce. So I decide to add this user ADMIN role, and then lower its privileges with custom code, if/else and custom redirections via functions.php.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).